# This computer has an IP address conflict with another computer

Tags: networking

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of the error message that says that my PC has an i.p. address conflict?

Comment: You need to change the IP address of one of the computers. You don't say what operating systems you are using so it's going to be difficult to suggest how exactly to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

It is more about correcting your computer IP address rather than trying to get rid of the conflict error message.

A conflict means you have ended up with an IP address already present on the network.
This could be because you 'randomly' happen to pick such an IP address when you setup your computer or because the local network administrator has messed up their DHCP settings.

If you are using a few computers in your home network with statically setup IP addresses, it is more likely that you used the same IP twice then a DHCP problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you log into your hub/router (192.168.0.1 usually) then under network or IP address in your router settings, you will see DHCP.

If DCHP is on, then you need to ensure that the range of IP addresses is enough for all of the devices you have, so all of your phones, printers, laptops, additional hubs or Wi-Fi points, powerline LAN plugs are all covered in your IP range – I usually set a range of 50 devices, so 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.52

If all of this is set, then as others have said, you need to ensure that your device is obtaining an IP address automatically and not assigning itself a manual address, as you need to be in the correct range and subnet to be able to log on to the router.

## For Windows

Right-click the connection that you want to change, and then select Properties. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Select the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, select either Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), and then select Properties.

To specify IPv4 IP address settings, do one of the following:
To get IP settings automatically using DHCP, select Obtain an IP address automatically, and then select OK.

To specify IPv6 IP address settings, do one of the following:
To get IP settings automatically using DHCP, select Obtain an IPv6 address automatically, and then select OK.

## For Mac

Go to system prefs, network, select your network (Wi-Fi / LAN).
Click Advanced, TCP/IP then make sure IPV4 is set to DHCP and IPv6 is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If your IP is set using DHCP (that is, if you did not manually set it up) then contact your system administrator. If you set it up manually, change it another IP within the subnet.